# How to specify an environment variable before npm install in package.json?

Tags: npm, environment-variables

**Situation**

Within the company we've got our own NPM registry and the corporate network blocks the access to the public NPM registry.

**Problem**

To install cypress, we would like the binary to be downloaded from our own NPM registry by running following command:

```
export CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=<Our NPM registry URL>
```

However it does not work if we add the above command into the `preinstall` hook. We believe it's because NPM runs each task in a separate process.

So my question is, how to export an environment variable for `npm install` to use in package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a line to the `.npmrc` file like this:

```
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY = https://some.registry
```

Which ends up in Cypress resolving the donwload from the URL specified.

```
[08:47:39]  Downloading Cypress     [started]
[08:47:39]  Downloading Cypress     [failed]
[08:47:39] → The Cypress App could not be downloaded.

Please check network connectivity and try again:

----------

URL: https://some.registry
Error: unable to reach host

----------
```